Classic ASP: Discern VBScript arrays in JScript code
I have a function in JScript that accepts a string or an array as parameter:
<script language="JScript" runat="server">
  function handleThis(what) {
    if (typeof what === 'string') {
      response.write("You provided: " + what + "\n");
    } else if (typeof what === 'object' && what.constructor === Array) { // JS array (ECMAScript3 has no Array.prototype.isArray())
      response.write("You provided: " + what.join(", ") + "\n");
    } else {
      response.write("The provided value is neither a string or an array.\n");
    }
  }
</script>

But then it always falls in "The provided value is neither a string or an array", and typeof what becomes unknown.
I tried checking for its type, and calling new Enumerator() similarly to the guide on traversing collections using JScript, from Microsoft, only to get Object not a collection:
var what_parsed;
try {
  what_parsed = new Enumerator(what);
} catch (e) {
  response.write("Unable to enumerate provided value: " + e.message);
  what_parsed = ["nothing I could understand"];
}

response.write("After a lot of effort, you provided: " + what_parsed.join(", ") + "\n");

Is there a way I could check that unkonwn type object and effectively parse or convert into the JScript scope, in a transparent manner for the user of that function?
I'd like to avoid having to convert (from VBScript) that array every time I want to pass a call for the JScript handlers.
For instance, if I call this from JScript, I get:
handleThis("one"); // get "You provided: one"
handleThis(["one", "two"]); // get "You provided: one, two"

But then from VBScript:
handleThis "one" ' get "You provided: one"
handleThis Array("one", "two") ' get "The provided value is neither a string or an array."

And if I add the try-catch block, the last command results in:
handleThis Array("one", "two")
 'Unable to enumerate provided value: Object not a collection
 'After a lot of effort, you provided: nothing I could understand


None of this helps us understand what your parsed data looks like. The code snippet is not enough to answer this question. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the behaviour.

What parsed data? I just want to be able to pass an array and print its string elements. I added examples of calls from both JScript (works) and VBScript (arrays won't work). The results are printed as page output.

That’s clearer, thank you. Now I understand what you’re asking, why do you think passing an object from one language to another is ever going to work? The simplest fix would be to use a delimited string as the argument then take that input when it’s a string and try and split it into an array.

It turns out there is an in-built JScript object call VBArray you can use to wrap a VB Safe Array object.

Why does that question not show in any of my searches and while making this question? That's exactly what I need, and I could find also documentation on this and other similar objects in JScript

The search I did was by typing site:stackoverflow.com vbscript array to jscript into Google.

1st result if I replicate the search  beats me
anyways, with that, all that was left is wrap the code in a try-catch, so that if the passed object from vb was not a VBScript array I would still report an error. not sure it's worth reopeing this just to describe the test with the reviewed code.
